# how to use inheritence in ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I hava a class called `QGNode` that extends `GNode` and a class `QGraph` that extends `Graph`. In `QGNode` constructor when I call `super` constructor with an argument `ArrayList<QGNode>` an error occurs. Am I misunderstand inheritance?

Here is my code:

```
0 public class QuestionGraph extends Graph{    
1
2   public QuestionGraph(ArrayList<QGNode> nodes) {
3      super(nodes);  
4  }
5 }

1 public class Graph {
2
3 ArrayList<GNode> nodes;
4
5  public Graph(ArrayList<GNode> nodes) {
6      this.nodes = nodes;
7 }
8 }
```

error occurs at line 3 and it's a syntax error and IDE suggest : 
`create method (java.Util.Arraylist) in QuestionGraph`

Comment: please add your code and error that it gives you! you include some other part of code here

Comment: Firstly, *always* specify what the error is. "an error occurs" isn't nearly as useful as "Line X causes error Y" (specifying X and Y). Secondly, I would really avoid using names like "GNode" and "QGNode". Thirdly, this is a dupe - I'll find the relevant duplicate...

Comment: thanks @jon . errors occur in calling super(nodes) and it doesn't recognize any suitable constructor for that given argument. those names are abbreviation of QuestionGraphNode and AnswerGraphNode

Comment: No, don't try to summarize the error - you copy paste it directly into the question. And I'd avoid abbreviations when they make it harder to distinguish between things at a glance.

Comment: @amirveyseh As Jon explains user should be able to get at a glance what actual problem is without going through the code and finding out the problem for himself. Pasting the error or providing screenshot of IDE error would help a lot.

Comment: However my problem was solved by answers given here and the previous same question but I have put the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance in Generics works a bit differently.
In Java `ArrayList<QGNode>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<GNode>`.

[Generics in Java and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

[image: Inheritance and generics from Oracle documentation]

[image: How it works from Oracle documentation]

Comment: @amirveyseh First you should get the hang of how generics work by understanding the material in Oracle documentation. _Hint You will have to generify the class itself and use extends i.e. Upper bound._ Notify me back if you have further queries.

Comment: thanks @Narendra Oracle website is banned in my country so I couldn't check it. How ever my problem was salved